# Narrowing type conversion in C++ using pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, type-conversion

I have been having some problems with downward type conversion in C++ using pointers, and before I came up with the idea of doing it this way Google basically told me this is impossible and it wasn't covered in any books I learned C++ from. I figured this would work...

```
long int TheLong=723330;
int TheInt1=0;
int TheInt2=0;
long int * pTheLong1 = &TheLong;
long int * pTheLong2 = &TheLong + 0x4;

TheInt1 = *pTheLong1;
TheInt2 = *pTheLong2;

cout << "The double is " << TheLong << " which is "
     << TheInt1 << " * " << TheInt2 << "\n";
```

The increment on line five might not be correct but the output has me worried that my C compiler I am using gcc 3.4.2 is automatically turning TheInt1 into a long int or something. The output looks like this...

> The double is 723330 which is 723330 * 4067360

The output from TheInt1 is impossibly high, and the output from TheInt2 is absent.

I have three questions...

Am I even on the right track?

What is the proper increment for line five?

Why the hell is TheInt1/TheInt2 allowing such a large value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TheInt2 = *pTheLong2;
```

This invokes undefined behavior, because the C++ Standard does **not** give any guarantee as to which memory location `pTheLong2` is pointing to, as it's initlialized as:

```
long int * pTheLong2 = &TheLong + 0x4;
```

`&TheLong` is a memory location of the variable `TheLong` and `pTheLong2` is initialized to a memory location which is either not a part of the program hence illegal, or its pointing to a memory location within the program itself, though you don't know  where exactly, neither the C++ Standard gives any guarantee where it's pointing to.

Hence, dereferencing such a pointer invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @Nawaz - because, `long int *` not `int *` or?

Comment: Ha, I see now your edit, but anyway, it's really strange (unless both `long int` and `int` are the same size:? )

Comment: @Kiril: The undefined-behavior has nothing to do with `long int` or `int`.

Comment: @Nawaz - your edit still does not explain why `&TheLong + 0x4` _will_ return not the wanted address. Anyway, I know where's the problem, just haven't used pointer arithmetics for a while and have forgotten some things.

Comment: @Kiril: What is the wanted address? I said the C++03 Standard doesn't give any guarantee of the memory layout of the program. So you cannot assume anything about that.

Comment: The way I understand the "problem" - `&TheLong` should point to the start of the long int (its address, and this is OK). The added `+0x4`, according to John Tate, should point to the second half of the `long int`. So, as Magnus Hoff said, John Tate probably needs something like `(int*)(&TheLong) + 1`. That was what I meant by "the wanted address" - the address of the second half of the `long int` (not the first 4B, but [5, 8] bytes, starting from 1).

Answer (score 5):

`int` is probably 32 bit, which gives it a range of -2*10^9 to 2*10^9.

In the line `long int * pTheLong2 = &TheLong + 0x4;` you are doing pointer arithmetic to a `long int*`, which means the address will increase by the size of `0x4` `long int`s. I guess you are assuming that `long int` is twice the size of `int`. This is absolutely not guaranteed, but probably true if you are compiling in 64 bit mode. So you want to add half the size of a `long int` -- exactly the size of an `int` under your assumption -- to your pointer. `int * pTheLong2 = (int*)(&TheLong) + 1;` achieves this.

You are on the right track, but please keep in mind, as others have pointed out, that you are now exploring undefined behaviour. This means that portability is broken and optimization flags may very well change the behaviour.

---

By the way, a more correct thing to output (assuming that the machine is little-endian) would be:

```
cout << "The long is " << TheLong << " which is "
     << TheInt1 << " + " << TheInt2 << " * 2^32" << endl;
```

---

For completeness' sake, a well-defined conversion of a 32 bit integer to two 16 bit ones:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    uint32_t fullInt = 723330;
    uint16_t lowBits  = (fullInt >>  0) & 0x0000FFFF;
    uint16_t highBits = (fullInt >> 16) & 0x0000FFFF;

    std::cout << fullInt << " = "
        << lowBits << " + " << highBits << " * 2^16"
        << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output: `723330 = 2434 + 11 * 2^16`

Answer (score 2):

> Am I even on the right track?

Probably not.  You seem confused.

> What is the proper increment for line five?

There are none.  Pointer arithmetic is possible only inside arrays, you have no arrays here.  So

```
long int * pTheLong2 = &TheLong + 0x4;
```

is undefined behavior and any value other than 0 (and possibly 1) by which you'd replace 0x4 would also be UB.

> Why the hell is TheInt1/TheInt2 allowing such a large value?

`int` and `long int` often have the same range of possible values.

Comment: > is undefined behavior and any value other than 0 (and possibly 1) by which you'd replace 0x4 would also be UB.

That doesn't explain the output.

> int and long int often have the same range of possible values.

I see, how can I ensure int stays 16 bit?

Comment: @John Tate: For integers of specific bit-sizes, please look into the standard headers `stdint.h` (C99) or `cstdint` (C++0x). They have types like `int16_t` which are guaranteed to be 16 bits wide.

Comment: @John, Trying to explain behavior when you have an UB is a futile exercise, anything can happen and the explanation of why a given implementation behaves as it does just will give you a false impression that you can count sometimes on a specific behavior.  Then there is no guarantee that any type is 16 bits.  On implementation where there is one, `short` is often a valid way to get it.  In C++0X, int16_t (from `<cstdint>`) will be a uniform way to get it when it exist.